# I want to make a history table of Item but its show error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm working on Project which is Inventory system, When I enter Item Stock first time its working fine even stockout process work fine but when the second entry with the same name came to table its show this error. I try too much and read a lot but couldn't find a solution. 
Basically, the purpose of this table is to make history of All item when this item Procured and when this item stockout.[image]

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Edit your question and show the error as text, not an image. It isn't readable. Also, show your table schema, and the code you're using.

Comment: Butt indeed...please help us so we can help you, post the error and try to explain a bit more clearly.

Comment: there is a problem in my database I read it again and again now fine but Can you tell me how can I make a multiple entry table but quantity is changed every time